# How to point sub-domain to other domain by dns?

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, hosting, nameservers

Example i have

- sub.mywebsite.com

---

- exampleDomain.com

i want to to make content (script example)  of sub.mywebsite.com show too in exampleDomain.com

like whats happen in Shopify (Shopify allow user to add his own-domain !
Who i can allow user link his own domain ?

Example 2 :

- https://user.myshopify.com/ - Deafult Domain
- https://www.userDomain.com/ - Addon Domain

Comment: You need to add support at a couple of levels: DNS, server and code. For DNS, you either manually create each entry, or you use a wildcard. For the server, you basically do the same, manually create virtual hosts or have a catch-all. And, in code, I guess you do the same, too, either keep duplicating your code, or have it inspect the headers to determine which site is being used. There’s also an option for putting your site into the [PSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Suffix_List) although that is a more advanced thing, generally.